# Is there a way in Java to sniff packets during a test similar to Wireshark?

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, wireshark, tshark

I have a manual test case that uses Wireshark to examine the connection details of a TLS handshake. Our test case has a server using TLS1.2, we would like to check that if our client using TLS1.3 and TLS1.2 falls back to using TLS1.2 during the handshake. We're looking to automate this test and was wondering if there is a way that could allow us to examine this in code.

I was thinking of a flow something like this, configuration of network interfaces can be done before this:

```
PacketSniffingLibrary.start() // this will start capturing packets now

test.postToSomeTls1.2Service() 

PacketSniffingLibrary.stop() // stop capturing packets

listOfPackets = PacketSniffingLibrary.getPackets() // return packets caught at that instance
```

Ideally, we could get the information such as Tls protocol used, etc. directly from the each item in the list, or a list of strings displaying the same information as if read from wireshark.

One option we thought of was to use `tshark` by using the `Process` class to run terminal commands, but was looking for cleaner options. I've researched about this but a lot of the libraries are quite outdated.

Comment: isn't -Djavax.net.debug=SSL enough ? Should log to System.out all the underlying informations

Comment: Haven't heard of this, but would this work for my case though? For more details, our functional test posts to the service we are testing (client) -> client makes an http request to another (mock) server -> server returns http status to client -> client returns http status back to our test. (Note: the client and server could possibly be on localhost or another ip)

Comment: just start the client providing -Djavax.net.debug=SSL and check its output.